# Estimating CVaR for non-Gaussian distributions

Tags: risk

Calculating CVaR needs Gaussian distribution, however, what if the distribution is not Gaussian? Or the distribution is unknown? Can I use many Dirac Delta functions to estimate a distribution and  estimate the CVaR？

Comment: Computing the conditional value at risk does not require the distribution to be Gaussian.

Comment: Thanks. For any distractions of cost, is CVaR always larger than the mean value?